# isinstance() and type() equivelence failure due to import mechanism (python/django)

Tags: python, django, types, import, isinstance

In a Django project I'm working on I import a form in the view as follows

```
#views.py
from forms import SomeForm
```

then in a test file I have

```
#form_test.py
from app.forms import SomeForm    
.
.
.
self.assertTrue(isinstance(response.context['form'], SomeForm))
```

Why doesn't the isinstance work?

If I inspect the output of type() for the two objects I get this:

response.context form:  
Expected form:

I can fix this by making my import mechanism in views.py match that in the form_test.py, but this seems like the wrong approach.

for reference, file structure as follows:

- site/

  - manage.py
  - app/

    - forms.py
    - views.py
    - tests/

      - form_test.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isinstance` also compare module location, `response.context['form']` class' module is `forms` where SomeForm module is `app.forms` you check this by inspecting respectively `__class__.__module__` and  `__module__`.

To make isinstance work you can:

- fix the import in the views.py (recommended)
- alter sys.path in form_testse.py to be able to import the form as from forms import SomeForm
- try [intrapackage references](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

Answer (score 0):

one possible hack is to check the `__name__` attribute of the types, although unless you fix it the Right way, you might run into other issues

```
def sharetypename(obj1, obj2):
    if isinstance(obj1, type):
        c1 = obj1.__name__
    else:
        c1 = type(obj1).__name__

    if isinstance(obj2, type):
        c2 = obj2.__name__
    else:
        c2 = type(obj2).__name__

    return c1 == c2
```